# How to convert motion sensor data from Iphone to Android?

Tags: iphone, android, accelerometer

I have some motion sensor samples that were recorded with an Iphone.
Now I'm into calculating a distance between a user gesture and the gesture that was recorded on the Iphone.

My problem is that the sensor data on the Iphone is represented in a different way then the android sensor data. If i don't move the Iphone I get data between -1 and 1 if I don't move my Android device I get values around 9 because the sensor measures the force of gravity.

I couldn't figure out how to convert the Iphone sensor reading to compare them to my android sensor readings. The android motion sensor data is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html). And the Iphone documentation contains this [pdf](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/UIAcceleration_Class.pdf).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745066/how-to-compare-accelerometer-values-in-ios-and-android

Answer (score 2):

I found same problem while porting iPhone application in Android. I found one solution. It's work for my application.

1. I found that iPhone's accelerometer value is between -2.5 and +2.5.
   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1743220?start=0&tstart=0
2. I found that Android's Sensor Class has method to find max value.
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getMaximumRange()

Now I put simple calculation like following

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float t = 2.5f / accMaxValue;
        Log.i(TAG,"onSensorChanged X "+ (event.values[0]*t) +"\t\t Y "+ (event.values[1]*t)+"\t\t Z "+ (event.values[2]*t) );
    }
```

Get Max value from Sensor

```
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    accMaxValue = mAccelerometer.getMaximumRange();
```