# How to compare accelerometer values in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

I get accelerometer values in iOS as follows

```
if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"Accelerometer avaliable");
        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"raw_accel_X==%f,date=%@",accelerometerData.acceleration.x,[NSDate date]);
                NSLog(@"raw_accel_Y==%f,date=%@",accelerometerData.acceleration.y,[NSDate date]);
                NSLog(@"raw_accel_Z==%f,date=%@",accelerometerData.acceleration.z,[NSDate date]);

        }];
```

If i don't move the Iphone I get data between -1 and 1 if I don't move my Android device I get values around 9. What should I do to match raw accelerometer values in iOS to that of Android?
Any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to understand how iOS accelerometer works. The output is mesured in [gforces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force), and there is a lot of noise with the data, so you have to normalize the data before analyzing it.

Android's accelerometer outputs acceleration in meters per second squared,if you want to convert the acceleration into a g-force measurement, divide it by 9.81 (gravitational pull on earth).

Comment: Alternatively you could also multiply the iOS values by 9.81 and keep your Android values as is.

Comment: You should multiple by -9.81